# Postgresql: SERIAL incremented on failed constraint INSERT

Tags: sql, postgresql

Having a simple table structure like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    sid SERIAL
);
```

I noticed if I attempt to insert a row but it fails a constraint test (i.e. PRIMARY KEY constraint), the `SERIAL` counter will increment anyway, so the next successful insert, `sid` will be `sid + 2` instead of `sid + 1`.

Is this normal behavior? Any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Yes, it is by design. `Serial` datatype uses sequences and this behavior is described in the documentation ([Sequence Manipulation Functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-sequence.html)):

> To avoid blocking concurrent transactions that obtain numbers from the
>   same sequence, a nextval operation is never rolled back; that is, once
>   a value has been fetched it is considered used, even if the
>   transaction that did the nextval later aborts. This means that aborted
>   transactions might leave unused "holes" in the sequence of assigned
>   values.

There is no way to prevent it efficiently. You may however develop your own sequence by creating a one-row table and locking it while fetching the next value.