# Why does Phoenix's Ecto skip IDs when the previous insert was an error?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am new to Phoenix and I was just playing around in iex when I noticed this happened. I was trying to insert a record and it had a validation error. After successfully inserting it, I found out the ID was not the next expected ID, so in my database it just has 2 records with ID 1 and 4.

Here is a log for example:

This is the first error, and notice the ID is 2.

```
iex(7)> Test.Projects.create_project(%{name: "Test", user: user})
[debug] QUERY ERROR db=3.6ms queue=6.4ms idle=1633.0ms
INSERT INTO "projects" ("name","inserted_at","updated_at") VALUES ($1,$2,$3) RETURNING "id" ["Test", ~N[2021-12-15 09:37:46], ~N[2021-12-15 09:37:46]]
** (Postgrex.Error) ERROR 23502 (not_null_violation) null value in column "user_id" of relation "projects" violates not-null constraint

    table: projects
    column: user_id

Failing row contains (2, Test, null, 2021-12-15 09:37:46, 2021-12-15 09:37:46).
    (ecto_sql 3.7.1) lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex:760: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.raise_sql_call_error/1
    (ecto 3.7.1) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:744: Ecto.Repo.Schema.apply/4
    (ecto 3.7.1) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:367: anonymous fn/15 in Ecto.Repo.Schema.do_insert/4
```

This is the second error, and notice the ID is 3.

```
iex(7)> user.id
1
iex(8)> Test.Projects.create_project(%{name: "Test", user_id: user.id})
[debug] QUERY ERROR db=2.1ms queue=2.1ms idle=1264.9ms
INSERT INTO "projects" ("name","inserted_at","updated_at") VALUES ($1,$2,$3) RETURNING "id" ["Test", ~N[2021-12-15 09:38:02], ~N[2021-12-15 09:38:02]]
** (Postgrex.Error) ERROR 23502 (not_null_violation) null value in column "user_id" of relation "projects" violates not-null constraint

    table: projects
    column: user_id

Failing row contains (3, Test, null, 2021-12-15 09:38:02, 2021-12-15 09:38:02).
    (ecto_sql 3.7.1) lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex:760: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.raise_sql_call_error/1
    (ecto 3.7.1) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:744: Ecto.Repo.Schema.apply/4
    (ecto 3.7.1) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:367: anonymous fn/15 in Ecto.Repo.Schema.do_insert/4
```

This was a successful insert, but notice it's ID is 4. I would have expected 2.

```
iex(8)> recompile
Compiling 2 files (.ex)
:ok
iex(9)> Test.Projects.create_project(%{name: "Test", user_id: user.id})
[debug] QUERY OK db=9.7ms queue=5.4ms idle=1907.0ms
INSERT INTO "projects" ("name","user_id","inserted_at","updated_at") VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4) RETURNING "id" ["Test", 1, ~N[2021-12-15 09:38:26], ~N[2021-12-15 09:38:26]]
{:ok,
 %Test.Projects.Project{
   __meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "projects">,
   id: 4,
   inserted_at: ~N[2021-12-15 09:38:26],
   name: "Test",
   updated_at: ~N[2021-12-15 09:38:26],
   user: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :user is not loaded>,
   user_id: 1
 }}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postgresql: SERIAL incremented on failed constraint INSERT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35849944/postgresql-serial-incremented-on-failed-constraint-insert)

Answer (score 1):

In short, this is expected behavior from the database to avoid ["... To avoid blocking concurrent transactions..."](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html)

If you log into Postgres and do a `\d+ <table_name>` on your table, you should see something like this:

```
my_db=# \d+ accounts
                                                              Table "public.accounts"
   Column    |              Type              | Collation | Nullable |               Default                | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
-------------+--------------------------------+-----------+----------+--------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id          | bigint                         |           | not null | nextval('accounts_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
 name        | character varying(255)         |           |          |                                      | extended |              | 
 balance     | integer                        |           |          |                                      | plain    |              | 
 inserted_at | timestamp(0) without time zone |           | not null |                                      | plain    |              | 
 updated_at  | timestamp(0) without time zone |           | not null |                                      | plain    |              | 
Indexes:
    "accounts_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "accounts_name_index" UNIQUE, btree (name)
Access method: heap
```

The `id` column is set to `nextval('accounts_id_seq'::regclass)`  which is a sequence. In the [PG Docs on Sequences](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html) it says that even if the transaction fails, as in your first instance, the `nextval`, will not be rolled back. Thus, the next transaction will receive the next number in the sequence.

This sort of bleeds into being more of a Postgres-related question rather than a Phoenix/Elixir/Ecto, but I can certainly understand the confusion for anyone getting started with things.